# numpy - Modifying slice of mask?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a 3-d matrix in numpy, and want to change only the certain values of a certain dimension using slicing, is that possible?  This is what I have, but the values are unmodified after running the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc

image_matrix_data = misc.imread('./some-image.jpg')
image_mask   = image_matrix_data[:, : ,0] < 150
image_matrix_data[image_mask][:,0] = 0

# expected to get a matrix where several of the values in 
# image_matrix_data[:, :, 0] are now 0, but not happening
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: The boolean mask makes a copy, so any changes to the slice modify that, not the original array.  `data[mask] = 0` works because the `=` immediately follows the advanced indexing.

Comment: You can just use : `image_matrix_data[image_mask,0] = 0`.

Comment: thanks @Divakar, that was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from Divakar above:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc

image_matrix_data = misc.imread('./some-image.jpg')
image_mask   = image_matrix_data[:, : ,0] < 150
image_matrix_data[image_mask, 0] = 0
```